# DateTime.TryParseExact with "ddd" format fails for all days except current

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I encountered a strange issue. It's Wednesday now, and:

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
   "Wed", "ddd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date); // true

DateTime.TryParseExact(
   "Mon", "ddd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date); // false
```

When I change local date on computer to Monday output swaps to 'false-true'.

Why does the parser depend on current date?

Comment: What is your cultureinfo? By passing `null` as argument you  use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which might use a different abbreviated name for monday than `Mon`. Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Which date would you expect for "Mon"? Next monday? Last monday?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? Your trying to construct a date time object given only one part of information, the day.

Comment: What is stranger is the 1st returns 7/1/2015 and the 2nd returns 1/1/0001.  It appears the 1st returns true because today is Wednesday and returns true, while the seconds returns false because today isn't Monday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *suspect* the problem is that you've got a very incomplete date format there. Usually, `DateTime.TryParseExact` will use the current time and date for any fields that aren't specified. Here, you're specifying the day of the week, which isn't really enough information to get to a real date... so I suspect that the text value is only being used to *validate* that it's a reasonable date, after defaulting the `DateTime` to "now". (In the cases where it does manage to parse based on just the day name, you end up with today's date.)

I've just done another test where we specify the day-of-month value as well, and that ends up with interesting results - it appears to use the first month of the current year:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{    
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        // Note: All tests designed for 2015.
        // January 1st 2015 was a Thursday.
        TryParse("01 Wed"); // False
        TryParse("01 Thu"); // True - 2015-01-01
        TryParse("02 Thu"); // False
        TryParse("02 Fri"); // True - 2015-01-02
    }

    private static void TryParse(string text)
    {
        DateTime date;
        bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(
            text, "dd ddd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 0, out date);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2:yyyy-MM-dd}", text, result, date);
    }
}
```

Changing the system date to 2016 gave results consistent with finding dates in January 2016.

Fundamentally, trying to parse such incomplete as this is inherently odd. Think carefully about what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I know the code looks odd. Basically, what I was trying to do is validate a piece of date-time (single datepart)  against an arbitrary format specifier. With minimum efforts =)

Comment: @ArturUdod: Right. Unfortunately this approach isn't going to work for that :( Additionally, I'm not sure it even makes sense - is "30" valid for "dd"? It depends on the month...

Comment: @Mark: I think we'd need to know a lot more about the real requirements before adding a real answer.

Comment: that's more like a different question=) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use regex if you are wanting validating part of a date?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ieokVz

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{

    string pattern = "(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)";

    string[] values = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun","Bun","Boo","Moo"};

    Console.WriteLine("");


    foreach(var val in values){

        Console.WriteLine("{0} ? {1}",val,Regex.IsMatch(val,pattern));

    }
    }
}
```

As per @Jon's comments
https://dotnetfiddle.net/I4R2ZT

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var matches = new HashSet<String>(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        string[] values = {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun","Bun","Boo","Moo","Foo","Bar"};


        foreach(var val in values){

            Console.WriteLine("{0} ? {1}", val, matches.Contains(val));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're *just* trying to see whether a value is one of a set of values, regex seems a curious way of proceeding rather than `HashSet<string>` or just `List<string>` if the list is small enough. I'd only use regular expressions for genuine *patterns*.

Comment: Agreed a HashSet or List would be much more efficient. However wouldn't it be harder to maintain for different cultures? Rather than a simple string for each culture you'd need to map a each key to a key in the resource or write something to do that magically for you.

Comment: Well I'd use `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames` - it's easy to create a list or a set from that, whereas with regular expressions you'd need to construct the regex, remembering what to quote etc. So no, I think my suggestion makes it *easier* to support multiple cultures, rather than harder :)

Comment: Brilliant I completely forgot about CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames thanks for the reminder :)